# Laravel: How to get the same data for more users?

Tags: php, laravel

I have code like this that works fine:

```php
return $user->statistics()
            ->selectRaw('created_at as date, MIN(level) as min_level, max(level) as max_level, SUM(level_change) as sum_level_change')
            ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7))
            ->groupByRaw('DAY(date)')
            ->latest()
            ->get();
```

```
[
{
"date": "2022-09-05 17:23:22",
"min_level": 2748,
"max_level": 2750,
"sum_level_change": "3"
},

{
"date": "2022-09-04 11:20:17",
"min_level": 2722,

"max_level": 2747,
"sum_level_change": "114"
},

{
"date": "2022-09-03 11:14:19",
"min_level": 2715,
"max_level": 2721,
"sum_level_change": "31"
},

{
"date": "2022-09-02 20:32:17",
"min_level": 2712,
"max_level": 2714,
"sum_level_change": "15"
},

{
"date": "2022-09-01 19:32:19",
"min_level": 2709,
"max_level": 2710,
"sum_level_change": "7"
},

{
"date": "2022-08-31 19:02:19",
"min_level": 2703,
"max_level": 2708,
"sum_level_change": "41"
},

{
"date": "2022-08-30 20:26:19",
"min_level": 2701,
"max_level": 2702,
"sum_level_change": "8"
}
]
```

However, I would also like to use this for more users. This is one of my attempts, but blank data is returned

```php
return $room->users()
            ->with('statistics', function ($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('created_at as date, MIN(level) as min_level, max(level) as max_level, SUM(level_change) as sum_level_change');
                $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7));
                $query->groupByRaw('DAY(date)');
            })
            ->limit(25)
            ->get();
```

```
[

{
"id": 1,
"room_id": 65,
"name": "XXX",
"level": 1012,
"created_at": "2022-07-25T18:04:04.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2022-09-06T03:29:23.000000Z",
"statistics": []
},

{
"id": 2,
"room_id": 65,
"name": "XXX",
"level": 6,
"created_at": "2022-09-03T19:32:19.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2022-09-03T19:38:19.000000Z",
"statistics": []
},
(...)
]
```

Could someone help me? I would like statistics to be assigned the same data as for one user and to be sorted according to the first array by sum_level_change.

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

> You can accomplish this by passing an array of relationships to the with method where the array key is a relationship name and the array value is a closure.

```
return $room->users()
    ->with('statistics' => fn ($query) => $query->selectRaw('created_at as date, MIN(level) as min_level, max(level) as max_level, SUM(level_change) as sum_level_change')
            ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7))
            ->groupByRaw('DAY(date)');
    })
    ->limit(25)
    ->get();
```